# Is there any way of accessing Recycle bin functions of OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

Is there a way of accessing Recycle bin functions (view, restore, delete) of OneDrive?

I tried using OneDrive API, went through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631819.aspx, also http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/Default.aspx but found nothing related to it.

Or maybe there is any other, undocumented way? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't expose recycle bin functionality through the OneDrive developer APIs today.  Any items you delete through the developer APIs, though, will wind up in the user's recycle bin.

Comment: Any future plans to expose it?

Comment: I can't comment on future plans for the APIs.  That said, we do realize that the developer APIs offer limited functionality today and we're looking into ways to improve them.

Comment: @ginach Has this changed at all? The web ui is horrendous to work with if you have LOTS of files you need to restore. For instance, I just accidentally whacked a folder with thousands of files and I need to restore them all. In the Web UI I'm unable to select all the files I need (while also excluding those I don't still need). The scroll jumps all around and unselects what was already selected, and then when the list re-hydrates often items are missing, so I have a hard time even trusting that I'm performing the right action on the right file..

Comment: No, there still isn't any recycle bin functionality exposed via the OneDrive API. You should request the feature on [UserVoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer). Also, the [API docs issues page](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues) is the best place for questions like this.